# Having difficulty enabling an authorized user to view their own resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a `User` able to edit their own `Dashboard`.

I am using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/tree/2.0) and [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to try to make this happen ([Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) is also installed to help with Admin features, but I don't feel it's applicable to this situation).

When I have a user logged in and they visit their :show dashboard page at root/users/id/dashboard.id they fail authentication although they have the same `user.id` as listed on the `dashboard.user_id` (as dictated in the `ability.rb` file.

**How do I ensure that a user can view their own dashboard?**

Here is the associated code:

`dashboards_controller.rb`:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:format])
    authorize! :read, current_user, :message => 'Not authorized to view this dashboard.'
  end
 end
```

`ability.rb`:

```
user ||= User.new

if user.has_role? :default # All of my users have this role
    can :read, Dashboard, :user_id => user.id
end
```

from `routes.rb`

```
resources :users do
  resource :dashboard, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

`User.rb`:

```
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string(255)
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0)
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string(255)
#  created_at             :datetime
#  updated_at             :datetime
#
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :dashboard
  before_create :build_dashboard

end
```

`Dashboard.rb`:

```
# Table name: dashboards
#
#  id                        :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id                   :integer
#  has_selected_account_type :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  created_at                :datetime
#  updated_at                :datetime
#
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions)

Basically, you want to use the `load_resource` helper method to fetch only current_user's dashboard. Behind the scene it is doing something like this in your controller:

```
current_user.dashboard.find(params[:dashboard_id])
```

Comment: In my case I removed the `authorize!` line from my controller and went with `load_and_authorize_resource` instead of just `load_resource` and it worked as desired.  Thanks.